# i need output in dictionary without using list,tuple,append

Tags: python

```
D={'name':'hello'}

output = {'n':'hello','a':'hello','m':'hello','e':'hello'}
```

need this output write a python code without using list,tuple,append

```
d = {'name': 'Hello'}
output = {}

for char in d['name']:
  output[char] = 'hello'
print(output)
```

but i got this output=`{'H': 'hello', 'e': 'hello', 'l': 'hello', 'o': 'hello'}`

I'm expecting output = `{'n':'hello','a':'hello','m':'hello','e'='hello}`

Comment: It seems you wanted `for char in 'name'` instead of `for char in d['name']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
D = {"name": "hello"}

out = dict.fromkeys("name", D["name"])
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'n': 'hello', 'a': 'hello', 'm': 'hello', 'e': 'hello'}
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
d = {'name': 'hello'}
print(dict.fromkeys(*d.popitem()))
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3LVIUbBWq1fMSc1PVrRTUM1JzcvLVa7kKijLzSjRSMpNL9NKK8nOzUyuLNbRS9AryCzJLUnM1NDU1IfqhxsCMAwA)):

```
{'n': 'hello', 'a': 'hello', 'm': 'hello', 'e': 'hello'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be iterating over the value from the dict rather than the key:

```
d = {'name': 'hello'}
output = {}

key = 'name'
for char in key:
  output[char] = d[key]
print(output)
```

Output as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Below loop iterates over the characters 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e' explicitly specified as a string, and each character is mapped to the string 'hello' in the output dictionary:

```
d = {'name': 'Hello'}
output = {}

for char in 'name':  
    output[char] = 'hello'

print(output)
```

Output:

```
{'n': 'hello', 'a': 'hello', 'm': 'hello', 'e': 'hello'}
```